# ios MasterDetail app: UITextField in tableview not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, textfield

I have a master detail app in ios, with SDK 7.0, Xcode 5, using ARC.

master has many items, detail has a table view. When I click on an item, the contents of tableview will change. This works well until I put a UITextField in each cell, because I want to edit the contents in the table.

The problem is: when I click on a new item, the old contents don't disappear，so the contents of a cell is a superposition of the new UITextField's text and the old UITextField's text.

The first normal tableview like this:
[image]

After I click on an new item, the tableview will like this:
[image]

The snippet of codes of master is:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    LHBPoetry *poetry = poetryArray[indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.poetryId = poetry.poetryId;
}
```

I have tried a lot of things in the above method, for example, I make all instances of the detail view controller to be nil; table view's data array removeAllObejects; table view reloadData; It can't fix the problem.

The snippet of detail is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"detailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    UITextField *textField = textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                                              CGRectMake(90, 12, 200, 25)];


    textField.tag = indexPath.row;
    textField.text =_sentenceArray[indexPath.row];

    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    [textField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDone:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

    textField.text = _sentenceArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I draw this tableview in Main.storyborad, It has a prototype cell with an identifier.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k there is something i want to tell, wy because u are keep on adding the textfields for reused cells, there is not one textfield in the cell ..:) there are more then one text field's, because of that u are getting overlapped with one other, i think u are using default "master- detail" application, and modifying it..:)

oky for that u need to modify like below

in master controller

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
      {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 3, 300, 30)];
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd]; //hear u are adding once initially
        textField.tag = 100;
        [cell addSubview:textField];
      }


   NSString *object = _objects[indexPath.row];//_objects is mutable array holding the sentences or names
   UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100];//after that u are reusing the textfields
   textField.text = object;
   textField.tag = indexPath.row;
   return cell;
  }
```

now you are creating the cell thats wy u dont want the prototype cell remove it from story board [image]

in the above u removed the custom cell becz u are creating the cell in the code it self

now in the method

```
  - (void) textFieldDone:(UITextField *)inTextFIeld
  {
       int index = inTextFIeld.tag;
       [_objects replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[inTextFIeld text]];
       [self.masterTableVIew reloadData];//made connection to ur tableview 

  }
```

Comment: I faced a problem in this way to create textFields: If the tableview has many rows, 5 rows in a page, when I scroll the table, some rows' contents are wrong, for example, the 6th row's content should be 6, but actually is 1...What can I do?

Comment: I mean after initialization of the table, the first five rows' value are 1,2,3,4,5 in the first page, they're all right. But when I scroll the table to see more rows after the first page, for example I scrolled a distance for one row, the values should be 2,3,4,5,6, but they are 2,3,4,5,1. When I scrolled randomly, the values are also randomly, they are all messed up